# ivy resolution error on case differences

Tags: grails, ivy, dependency-management

In my Grails 2.4.1 config, I tried to create a chain resolver. I am chaining two stores - 3rdparty and myproject. The chained resolver is named "internal". When I use the chain resolver, I get the following error:

```
3rdpartyLib: bad revision found in http://<MY_REPO>/3rdpartycache/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.pom: expected='1.1.0.Final found='1.1.0.FINAL'
```

I also get the following warning about unresolved dependencies:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://<MY_REPO>/3rdpartycache/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.pom': bad revision: expected='1.1.0.Final' found='1.1.0.FINAL'; 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

When, instead, I just use the 3rdparty resolver, this resource is found:

```
|Downloading: validation-api-1.1.0.FINAL.pom.sha1
    found javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.FINAL in 3rdpartyLib
    found org.grails.plugins#tomcat;7.0.54 in cache
...
downloading http://<MY_REPO>/3rdpartycache/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.FINAL/validation-api-1.1.0.FINAL.jar ...
|Downloading: validation-api-1.1.0.FINAL.jar.sha1
    [SUCCESSFUL ] javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.FINAL!validation-api.jar (88ms)
|Downloading: jandex-1.1.0.Final.pom.sha1
    found org.jboss#jandex;1.1.0.Final in 3rdpartyLib
    found javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.FINAL in cache
    [1.1.0.FINAL] javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final **(forced)**
```

What I find interesting is the "forced" log statement. Notice that it found the FINAL version here.

I defined the resolvers in the following methods:

```
def internalChainResolver()
{
    ChainResolver resolver = new ChainResolver()
    resolver.name = "internal"
    resolver.dual = true

    resolver.add thirdPartyLibrariesResolver()
    resolver.add myprojectLibraries()

    def ivySettings = new IvySettings()
    ivySettings.defaultInit()
    resolver.settings = ivySettings

    return resolver
}

def thirdPartyLibrariesResolver()
{
    IBiblioResolver resolver = new IBiblioResolver()
    resolver.name = "3rdpartyLib"

    resolver.root = "http://<MY_REPO>/3rdpartycache/"
    resolver.m2compatible = true

    def ivySettings = new IvySettings()
    ivySettings.defaultInit()
    resolver.settings = ivySettings

    return resolver
}

def myprojectLibraries()
{
    IBiblioResolver resolver = new IBiblioResolver()
    resolver.name = "myproject"

    resolver.root = "http://<MY_REPO>/myproject/"
    resolver.m2compatible = true

    def ivySettings = new IvySettings()
    ivySettings.defaultInit()
    resolver.settings = ivySettings

    return resolver
}
```

And here is the resolver and resolution block:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy" // or  maven
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    }
    log 'info' // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        resolver internalChainResolver()
        //        resolver thirdPartyLibrariesResolver()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
         test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
        build 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.FINAL'
        runtime 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.5.RELEASE'
        runtime 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.5.RELEASE'
        runtime 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.1.RELEASE'
        runtime 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA'
        runtime 'com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0'

    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"
        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.6'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    }
}
```

I have searched repeatedly for insight and have done a lot of reading, but have yet to see an answer. I have mined the depths of my Ivy knowledge and integration with Grails.

I am looking for suggestions regarding how to make the chain resolver work for we will need to add multiple libraries for this and other projects.

**### EDIT ###**

I changed the chain resolver so that myproject is added before 3rdparty. This fails as described above.

I changed the chain resolver so that it only included the 3rdparty resolver. This fails also. Oddly, in my opinion or lack of understanding, for having chain resolver that contains only one chain resolver, it seems to me, should be substitutable for the given resolver.

It doesn't seem logical to me that using a chained resolver should cause resolution to fail. We are thinking that when we do not use the chain resolver, the resolution is happening via the .m2 cache and "something" (is maven actually being used to read the .m2 cache even though I specified Ivy?) is smart enough to not care about case. Whereas when we create the chain resolver, which is specifically an Ivy thing, Ivy does not handle the case difference. Purely a hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is likely caused by the scope you are using for your jar (build). When Grails is using ivy to resolve its dependent jars it is also retrieving the transitive dependencies of all of the jars it is pulling. What is likely happening is that you have a "runtime" dependent jar with a transitive dependency on the validation-api jar. Try updating your scope to "runtime" and that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem, located at the end of the error message

> 3rdpartyLib: bad revision found in 
>   http:///3rdpartycache/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.pom:
>   expected='1.1.0.Final found='1.1.0.FINAL'

Check the version field in the POM file. The version field is case sensitive. Looks like a repository problem.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. This resolves just fine without using the chain resolver, but it will *not* resolve when using the chain resolver. The difference is that chain resolver version links the 3rdparty resolver and the myproject resolver. The chained resolver is called internal. If I substitute internal for 3rdparty, it resolves. If instead I used internal, which by definition includes 3rdparty, it will not resolve. As this means only the addition of the myproject resolver, the error does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Note the highighted sample states the bad revision was found in 3rdparty library, it does not complain in the unchained version: |Downloading: validation-api-1.1.0.FINAL.pom.sha1
    found javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.FINAL in 3rdpartyLib
    found org.grails.plugins#tomcat;7.0.54 in cache
...
downloading http://<MY_REPO>/3rdpartycache/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.FINAL/validation-api-1.1.0.FINAL.jar ...
|Downloading: validation-api-1.1.0.FINAL.jar.sha1
    [SUCCESSFUL ] javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.FINAL!validation-api.jar (88ms)

Comment: down voting for this response only re-stated the problem. it did not take into account that there should have been no difference, or at least, did not explain why this error would appear only when using the chained resolver.

Comment: @BillTurner Down-voting answers before the author has had a chance to respond is not going  to encourage others to help you. Best of luck!

Comment: point taken. if you edit the answer, i will change my vote. i cannot change it, apparently, unless it is edited.